# JBoss AS 7 maven dependency for standalone client

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

We have a standalone desktop client that connects to a JBoss server. For version 6 of JBoss the maven dependency used by the desktop client project was

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For JBoss 7.1.1 no such dependency exists. What is the correct maven dependency that should be used when developing a standalone desktop client?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you directly connect to EJB you need the EJB client libs.In earlier versions of JBoss AS7 there were a bunch of individual dependencies required. Starting (AFAIK) from `7.1.1-Final` a BOM (bill of materials) is available:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You will find [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI) detailed information on JNDI lookups and invoking methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the JBoss AS 6 client, but for the JBoss AS 7 one you would need the following.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-controller-client</artifactId>
        <version>${as.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You'll be using the `org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient` for standalone or `org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.domain.DomainClient` for domain mode.